# celery Bad magic number in docker

Tags: python, django, docker, celery

I can run the celery beat normally using the command in the terminal, but when I go to run with docker I get the following error:

```
[2019-03-11 11:46:27,327: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
celery_beat_taxithe | [2019-03-11 11:46:27,489: ERROR/MainProcess] Removing corrupted schedule file 'celerybeat-schedule': error('Bad magic number',)
celery_beat_taxithe | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_beat_taxithe |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
celery_beat_taxithe |     return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
celery_beat_taxithe | KeyError: 'scheduler'
celery_beat_taxithe | 
celery_beat_taxithe | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
celery_beat_taxithe | 
celery_beat_taxithe | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_beat_taxithe |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 476, in setup_schedule
celery_beat_taxithe |     self._store = self._open_schedule()
celery_beat_taxithe |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 466, in _open_schedule
celery_beat_taxithe |     return self.persistence.open(self.schedule_filename, writeback=True)
celery_beat_taxithe |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shelve.py", line 243, in open
celery_beat_taxithe |     return DbfilenameShelf(filename, flag, protocol, writeback)
celery_beat_taxithe |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/shelve.py", line 227, in __init__
celery_beat_taxithe |     Shelf.__init__(self, dbm.open(filename, flag), protocol, writeback)
celery_beat_taxithe |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dbm/__init__.py", line 94, in open
celery_beat_taxithe |     return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
celery_beat_taxithe | _gdbm.error: Bad magic number
```

My settings of celery is:

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'driver_monitor_update_latlng': {
        'task': 'api.tasks.driver.turn_offline_driver',
        'schedule': 30.0 # a cada 30 seconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried use with crontab ? like this:

from celery.schedules import crontab


CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'run-every-20-min': {
        'task': 'tasks.your-task',
        'schedule': timedelta(minutes=20),
        'args': ()
    },

Comment: Yes, and no work. When i use crontab i get this error "apps aren't loaded yet". Same i including depends_on of redis, web app(django) e celery worker

Comment: In my machine using without crontab same with error message the task will running but in the server when i see logs of celery-beat service always in [2019-03-11 13:58:00,740: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing .0 from 30.0. Probably not the issue but it's something to do with your number or the way you're handling it.

Comment: in the documentation is like my code but i removed and the problem continue :(